# Time Complexity of Next Greater Element

Tags: java, performance, big-o

I have solved Next Greater Element problem in reference to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/) question from GeeksforGeeks. I quite confused to find the time complexity(Big O) for the below problem.
It would be really helpful if anybody can help me on this.

Question:
Given an array, print the Next Greater Element (NGE) for every element. The Next greater Element for an element x is the first greater element on the right side of x in array. Elements for which no greater element exist, consider next greater element as -1.

Examples:

a) For any array, rightmost element always has next greater element as -1.

b) For an array which is sorted in decreasing order, all elements have next greater element as -1.

1. 

How to find the time complexity of this?

Is this is the acceptable way of solving this problem?

```
    int[] array = {20,10,5,3};

    int len =array.length;
    int[] temp = new int[len];

    int j=0;
    int i=j;
    while(j<len-1){
        ++i;
        if(i>=len){
            System.out.println(array[j]+"----> -1");
            j++; i=j;
            continue;
        }
        if(array[j]<array[i]){
            System.out.println(array[j]+"----> "+array[i]);
            j++; i=j;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(array[j]+"----> -1");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having difficulties deciding the complexity of your algorithm because you are using `continue`, which adds unnecessary difficulty to your reasoning.

Rewriting to the following (without using `break` or `continue`):

```
public void test() {
    int[] array = {10, 20, 3, 5};

    int len = array.length;

    for (int j = 0; j < len - 1; j++) {
        int nge = -1;
        for (int i = j + 1; i < len && nge < 0; i++) {
            if (array[j] < array[i]) {
                nge = array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(array[j] + "----> " + nge);
    }
    System.out.println(array[len-1] + "----> -1");
}
```

It is now clear that this is `O(n lg n)` because the outer loop iterates to `n` and the inner by up to `n - j`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. so you mean to say, both approach takes same complexity?. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @Sreekrishnan - I am saying that if the algorithm is correctly implemented then the **algorithm** has the stated complexity. We have both implemented the algorithm correctly but your implementation is very difficult to reason about because you have used a `continue` to achieve the inner loop. Mine more clearly exposes the algorithm as two loops, one inside the other. Yours performs the two iterations (of both `j` and `i`) in one loop.

Comment: I got your point, but how about performance improvement on both of the approach. As said, is there anything like inner loop is better than doing with continue and break?

Comment: @Sreekrishnan - The performance of the two will be effectively the same. There may be a few nanoseconds difference on some machines but essentially there is no difference. The very important point I am trying to make is that **you cannot improve performance of an algorithm beyond it's inherent complexity**.